# I am trying to reference an element on Target's website, but am having issues grabbing it

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, screen-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape some Target product information and am running into an issue trying to reference the UPC digits.

I am using Selenium on Python and am trying to reference the UPC and the digits, but there doesn't seem to be a way to reference the digits portion of it. I am currently trying:

```
UPC = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'UPC')]]")
```

But this only returns the string 'UPC' and not the digits.

Does anyone know how to reference the entire element? I posted some images along with this, thank you!

Comment: Can you share the page link or at least the HTML code? Not only of that single element.

Comment: without the page link or html, difficult to help you

Comment: Please share HTML code for that same.

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the *target product information* element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  UPC = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'UPC')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```